# How can I change the background color of the <body> element in Fable / Fulma?

Tags: f#, bulma, fable-f#

Here's a snippet of my client web app written in F# using Fable (for compilation to Javascript) and Fulma (for CSS rendering)

```
let view (model: MyModel) dispatch =
    div [ Style [CSSProp.BackgroundColor "green"]] [
         Button.button  [ Button.Size IsSmall ]  [ str "START" ]
    ]
```

Currently, only the background color of the `div` block is set to green. I know I could hard-code this into `index.html` or `bulma.css` to change the background color of the entire HTML page but I am looking for a way to do this in F# according to the rules established by Fulma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After studying the layout options of Fulma/Bulma [here](https://fulma.github.io/Fulma/) I was able to change the background color of the entire page in a Fulma-compliant way:

```
let view (model: MyModel) dispatch =
    Hero.hero [ Hero.Color IsSuccess
                Hero.IsFullHeight ]
               [ Hero.body []
                          [ Button.button []
                              [ str "START" ]]]
```

As a matter of fact, the `Hero` layout option proved to be quite versatile, e.g. you can have different portions of the background covered with `Hero.IsLarge`, `Hero.IsHalfHeight` etc ...

Answer (score 2):

I have not actually used Fulma myself, but I had a quick look at [the default Fulma template](https://github.com/Fulma/Fulma/tree/master/templates/Content). The way this works is that you have a `<div>` element with id `elmish-app` in the `index.html`:

```html
<body>
    <div id="elmish-app"></div>
</body>
```

And the F# code specifies to use the `<div>` element to show the elements generated by `view`:

```ml
Program.mkProgram init update view
|> Program.withReactSynchronous "elmish-app"
|> Program.run
```

Given this, you could try to add `id` to your `body` element and then generate HTML content including the `body` element in your view. If React actually replaces the original element with whatever you generated from `view` (rather than just adding that as nested element), this trick could work.

Comment: Unfortunately (or rather consequently) React does indeed add everything generated by `view` as nested element. But thanks to your hint I was able to figure out how it works in Fulma style. See answer below.

Comment: @Angle.Bracket Glad you figured it out. I upvoted your answer, but alas, it seems I cannot downvote mine!